# Java MisMatchException when I have a whitespace

Tags: java, file, netbeans, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a problem in `case 9` I want to write something in my code. When I write a `String` without any whitespaces like `("huhuu")`it will write in my file. But when I input a `String` that contains a white space e.g `"Hey you"`, it returns an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at assignment3.Main.main(Main.java:60)
C:\Users\Nigel Andam\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Right now I have this code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment3;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author Nigel Andam
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

        int choice;
        do {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please choose an option: \n"
                + "[1] - create Directory \n"
                + "[2] - create Multiple Directory \n"
                + "[3] - create File \n"
                + "[4] - rename a  File/Directory \n"
                + "[5] - copy a File/Directory \n"
                + "[6] - move a File/Directory \n"
                + "[7] - hide a File/Directory \n"
                + "[8] - unhide a File/Directory \n"
                + "[9] - write a Text File \n"
                + "[10] - read a Text File \n"
                + "[0] - exit");    
            System.out.println();
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                CreateDirectory cd = new CreateDirectory();
                String directory = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory = sc.next();
                Path path = Paths.get(directory);
                if(isValidPath(directory)) {
                     cd.createDirectory(path.toString());
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path.toString() + " is valid? " + isValidPath(path.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                CreateMultipleDirectory mcd = new CreateMultipleDirectory();
                String directory2 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory2 = sc.next();
                Path path2 = Paths.get(directory2);
                if(isValidPath(directory2)) {
                    mcd.createMulipleDirectory(directory2);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path2.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path2.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                CreateFile cf = new CreateFile();
                String directory3 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory3 = sc.next();
                Path path3 = Paths.get(directory3);
                if(isValidPath(directory3)) {
                    String fileName, extensionFile = null;
                    System.out.print("Filename first: ");
                    fileName = sc.next();
                    System.out.print("Extension File: ");
                    extensionFile = sc.next();
                    cf.createFile(path3.toString(), fileName, extensionFile);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path3.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path3.toString()));
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                RenameDirectoryFile rdf = new RenameDirectoryFile();
                String directory4 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory4 = sc.next();
                File src = new File(directory4);
                Path path4 = Paths.get(directory4);
                if(isValidPath(directory4)) {
                    System.out.print("New filename: ");
                    String newFileName = sc.next();
                    rdf.rename(src, newFileName);
                }else {
                     System.out.println(path4.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path4.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                CopyFile ccf = new CopyFile();
                String source, destination = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                source = sc.next();
                System.out.print("Destination where to copy: ");
                destination = sc.next();
                Path path11 = Paths.get(source);
                Path path12 = Paths.get(destination);
                if(isValidPath(source) && isValidPath(destination)) {
                    File src2 = new File(source);
                    File dest = new File(destination);
                    ccf.copyFile(src2, dest);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path11.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path11.toString()));
                    System.out.println(path12.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path12.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                MoveFile mf = new MoveFile();
                String source2, destination2 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                source2 = sc.next();
                System.out.print("Destination where to move: ");
                destination2 = sc.next();
                Path path13 = Paths.get(source2);
                Path path14 = Paths.get(destination2);
                if(isValidPath(source2) && isValidPath(destination2)) {
                    File src3 = new File(source2);
                    File dest2 = new File(destination2);
                    mf.move(src3, dest2);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path13.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path13.toString()));
                    System.out.println(path14.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path14.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                HideFile hf = new HideFile();
                String directory5 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory5 = sc.next();
                Path path6 = Paths.get(directory5);
                if(isValidPath(directory5)) {
                    hf.hideFile(directory5);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path6.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path6.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                UnHideFile uhf = new UnHideFile();
                String directory6 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory6 = sc.next();
                Path path7 = Paths.get(directory6);
                if(isValidPath(directory6)) {
                    uhf.unHideFile(directory6);
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path7.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path7.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 9:

                String directory7 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory7 = sc.next();
                Path path8 = Paths.get(directory7);
                if(isValidPath(directory7)) {
                System.out.print("Filename: ");
                String fileName = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Extension File: ");
                String extension = sc.next();
                File file = new File(directory7 + "\\" + fileName + extension); 
                    if(!file.exists()) {
                        Path path10 = Paths.get(directory7);             
                        CreateFile cf2 = new CreateFile();
                        cf2.createFile(path10.toString(), fileName, extension);
                        String write;
                        System.out.print("Write something");
                        write = sc.next();
                        WriteFile wf = new WriteFile("Hello World");
                        wf.writeFile(file);
                      }
                }else {
                    System.out.println(path8.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path8.toString()));
                }    
                break;
            case 10:
                String directory8 = null;
                System.out.print("Enter Path: ");
                directory8 = sc.next();
                Path path10 = Paths.get(directory8);
                File f3 = new File(path10.toString());
                if(isValidPath(directory8)) {
                    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
                    rf.readFile(f3);
                }else {
                     System.out.println(path10.toString() + " is valid " + isValidPath(path10.toString()));
                }
                break;
            case 0:

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                break;
        }
        }while (choice !=0);
    }
      public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
            try {
                Paths.get(path);
            } catch (InvalidPathException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

With a class of WriteFile

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment3;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 *
 * @author Nigel Andam
 */
public class WriteFile {
    private String write;
    public WriteFile(String write) {
//        System.out.println("WRITE FILE");
        this.write = write;
    }
    public String getWrite() {
        return write;
    }
     public void writeFile(File file) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(getWrite());
//            bufferedWriter.newLine();// append a newline character.
//            bufferedWriter.write("writing text after newline");
            bufferedWriter.close();// Always close files.
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to write file '" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you trued using “scanner.nextLine()” instead of next? Since you want an string from the line even if they have space then get the whole line instead of one token.

Comment: Thank you sir. Wait for a moment I will try this

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee when I use `nextLine()` I can't input a string. But when I use `next()` I can input a string, but still I got an exception

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the exception occurs?

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee it rejects the `nextLine()` so that I can't input a String.

Comment: What do you mean rejects the nextLine()?

Comment: @NigelPerey I think I know... try adding `sc.nextLine()` after you input the very first number in `choice = sc.nextInt()`, but otherwise keep the code same.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder 

Here 's the error

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at assignment3.Main.main(Main.java:60)
C:\Users\Nigel Andam\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)`

Comment: @NigelPerey I understand **what** the exception is, but it should also be highlighting a line from your code when the Exception occurs. Also, refer to my latest comment.

Comment: you should look up the difference between next(), nextLine() and nextInt().

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder when I used `nextLine()` the program is not asking to input a string. Most likely that code isn't reading when I run my program

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder In the main class the exception was pointing to `choice = sc.nextInt(); `

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I have already tried the `nextLine()` but still the program isn't reading that when I run the program

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder I have added the sc.nextLine(); after the `choice = sc.nextInt();` but still the exception is pointing on that code `choice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would grab the entire line of input when you just want a string from the user. Replace all `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine()`. Then create a function that gets input from the user that is an Integer and replace all occurrences of `sc.nextInt()` with your function call.

```
public static int getNumberFromUser(Scanner scan)
{
    boolean userEnteredNumber = false;
    while(!userEnteredNumber)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        String inputFromUser = scan.nextLine();
        if(inputFromUser.matches("\\d+"))
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(inputFromUser);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Input Not an Integer - " + inputFromUser);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now call this method when you want to get a number from the user instead of using `nextInt()` like so

```
choice = getNumberFromUser(sc);
```

Comment: I have try your code and all of your comments, but still the line `String write = sc.nextLine();` Is not reading my program when I run it. After I input the directory,filename,extension file and create a file.

Then goes to choosing an option again

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "Is not reading my program". what switch case are you referring to? case 9? and you won't write to the file unless your file exists based on your if(!file.exists())

Comment: Wait it's working but I'm gonna try again if the other case is not affected or still working